# How to populate dropdown list from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

So here I'm trying to populate my dropdown list, the code behind is as below:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CommonFunctions.GetAppDBConnection(Constants.AppID, Constants.TMDDBConnection));
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand("select * from MSUnit", con);
        SqlDataReader ddlvalues = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
        ddlTransactionCategory.DataSource = ddlvalues;
        ddlTransactionCategory.DataTextField = "categoryCode";
        ddlTransactionCategory.DataValueField = "OrgID";
        ddlTransactionCategory.DataBind();


        mycommand.Connection.Close();
        mycommand.Connection.Dispose();
    }
```

the problem is, I can't seem to get it to work, any help? and is this code doing it right?

Comment: ddlvalues is a SqlDataReader. It is not a valid DataSource for a Dropdown control. You should get the values in ddlvalues and put it in an appropriate container, say a generic list, and that's what you assign as the DataSource. And dispose the SqlDataReader after use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plz try below code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CommonFunctions.GetAppDBConnection(Constants.AppID, Constants.TMDDBConnection));
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand("select * from MSUnit", con);
    SqlDataAdapter adp =new   SqlDataAdapter(mycommand);
    DataSet ds =new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds);
    ddlTransactionCategory.DataSource = ds;
    ddlTransactionCategory.DataTextField = "categoryCode";
    ddlTransactionCategory.DataValueField = "OrgID";
    ddlTransactionCategory.DataBind();


    mycommand.Connection.Close();
    mycommand.Connection.Dispose();
}
```

Thanks,
Hitesh

Answer (score 0):

Can't bind to a SqlDataReader (or at least I've never tried it). Get a DataTable or a DataSet instead, fill it and then bind that to the dropdown the same way.

Comment: didn't see you wrote the same thing , I was going to give an example of datatable ...

Comment: could you provide example, please?

Answer (score 0):

Use SqlDataAdataper like the one below

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CommonFunctions.GetAppDBConnection(Constants.AppID, Constants.TMDDBConnection)))
{
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from MSUnit", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        ddlTransactionCategory.DataSource = dt;
        ddlTransactionCategory.DataTextField = "categoryCode";
        ddlTransactionCategory.DataValueField = "OrgID";
        ddlTransactionCategory.DataBind();
}
```

if you want to use DataReader you must insert one-by-one.

```
while (ddlvalues.Read())
{
    ddlTransactionCategory.Items.Add(new ListItem(ddlvalues.getString("OrgID"),ddlvalues.getString("categoryCode"))) 
}
```